# Directly parse data on nested proc macro

Tags: rust, rust-macros

Suppose this:

```
#[route(base_path="/api")]
pub struct Type;

impl Type {
  
   #[route(path="/v1/handler")]
   pub fn handler() {}

   #[route(path="/v1/handler2")]
   pub fn handler2() {}
}
```

I want to parse in any kind of data struct some mapping between the `base_path` and the `path` attached to the methods on the impl block. Imagine any HashMap<K, V> where `base_path` are the keys and `path` it's related values.

```
// pseudo struct internal data representation
[
    {
        struct: MyRestController, 
        base_path: "/api", 
        paths: [
            "handler", "handler2"
        ]
    },
    // other types registered
]
```

Is it possible to know with the proc-macro attached to the struct, detect the attributes attached to the methods on the impl block and made the parse in one type? (When the macro attached to the struct runs).

Comment: Proc-macro knows only about its own import (in case of attributes - only about the item), it can't resolve `impl` block from `struct` and vice versa. Do you want your code to work literally as written, or can you move the `base_path` on the `impl`?

Comment: @Cerberus is it possible to move the attribute to the `impl`block? Or I am understanding bad things?
W'd be no problem in move the `base_path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to write your macro so that it expects the following:

```
pub struct Type;

#[route(base_path="/api")]
impl Type {
  
   #[route(path="/v1/handler")]
   pub fn handler() {}

   #[route(path="/v1/handler2")]
   pub fn handler2() {}
}
```

That is, it wouldn't know anything about the struct itself (i.e. its fields), but it will have full access to the `impl` block, including attributes on individual functions.

Comment: Almost. Updated code for clarifying. I still don't know if it's possible to relationate them as in the pseudo-code provided in the update, by just parsing the attr on the `impl Type` block, detect the others and avoid N aditional macro runs in the handlers (the methods in the impl block declared as subpaths)

Comment: Attribute on the `impl` block can remove attributes from individual functions, since its output replaces the item entirely (unlike `derive` macros).

Comment: Aaaah! True. Forgot about that. Obviously, I can retrieve it's value before they gone, true?

Comment: Of course. You have the whole `impl` block as input and can output whatever you need - including the same `impl` block with arbitrary modifications.